# Error in nested loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, each, fields-for

I'm trying to make a report with predefined questions.
I have made questions from the scaffold and filled it.
Now is to assign answer fields per each questions.

```
[DATA TYPE]
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ansbwer_singles
end

class AnswerSingle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :report
end

reports/_form.html.erb
  <div class="question">
    <% QuestionSingle.all.each_with_index do |question, index| %>
  <p><%= index+1 %>. <%= question.content %></p>
  <p>
    <%= f.fields_for :answer_singles do |answer| %>
      <%= answer.text_area :content %>
    <% end %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

it shows well but once submit it makes error

```
1. Question 1
[text area]
2. Question 2
[text area]

[error when submit]
AnswerSingle(#18194030) expected, got Array(#1133380)
```

I think the reason is using `:answer_singles` for fields for.
Is there any better code to implement this?